# Not able to get values of textbox and label using asp.net and jquery from aspgrid (dynamic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have following grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdBOQ" width="100%"  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"  CssClass="gvBOQdatatable">

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No:">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#(grdBOQ.PageSize * grdBOQ.PageIndex) + grdBOQ.Rows.Count + 1%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Category_Name") %>' ID="lblCategoryName" ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>


               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category Description">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' ID="lblCategoryDescription" ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>


             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" class="form-control"  runat="server" Text="0" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UOM_Name") %>' ID="lblUnit" ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>


              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Rate">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SellingPrice_Per_UOM") %>' ID="lblUnitRate" ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label runat="server" Text='0.00' ID="lblTotalPrice" ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>



        </Columns>

              <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div style="width: 99%; text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" runat="server" Text="Sorry!!! No Record Found.."></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>

             </asp:GridView>
```

I have given following code in script tag using jquery to find asp textbox value but not working. I tried 2 different way but not getting.

```
First way
 $("#txtQuantity").on('click', function () {
                     alert('testing');
                 });

Second Way
     var recipient = $("#txtQuantity")
             $("#<%=recipient.ClientID%>").on('change', function () {
                alert('testing');
             });
```

Nothing works what is the way to get. I tried the above code inside document.ready and inside aspcontent tag.As it is in grid I have now around 5 textboxes and it varies based on the values from database.

Comment: try `keypress()`?

Comment: it shows error in all situation as , " it doesn't exist in current context"

Comment: Where the error thrown from? "Doesn't exist in current context" always means the identifier doesn't exist either in designer or code-behind.

Comment: The above error shows in visual studio and when I run I get compilation error as Line 166:             $("#<%=recipient.ClientID%>").on('change', function () {

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have some thing like this but no idea this is a good solution.Please advice

```
$("#<%=grdBOQ.ClientID %>").on('change', function () {

                 var GridView1 = document.getElementById('<%= grdBOQ.ClientID %>');
                 for (var rowId = 1; rowId < GridView1.rows.length; rowId++) {

                     var textValue = GridView1.rows[rowId].cells[3].children[0];
                     if (textValue.value != '0')
                     alert(textValue.value);
                 }


             });
```